# "Text File Busy" when running a simple script on bash

Tags: bash

When I make a simple script, I get "Text File Busy" when I try to run it.

```
dbell@det-ui-supergbe:~$ cat > test2
ls
^Z
[2]+  Stopped                 cat > test2
dbell@det-ui-supergbe:~$ chmod a+x test2
dbell@det-ui-supergbe:~$ ./test2
-bash: ./test2: Text file busy
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By hitting `Ctrl-Z` you suspended the `cat`, therefore the file is still open and being written to "in the background".

I suspect you want `Ctrl-D` for 'end of file'.

It's true that `Ctrl-Z` can mean 'EOF', but in this case, because you're in a terminal that supports background tasks, `Ctrl-Z` means 'suspend'.

[Try this link](http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/features_5.html) for more information.